# How can I search a list in python and print at which location(s) in that list my criteria is located?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, enumerate

I am generating a list of 12 random numbers:

```
nums = []    
for num in range(12):
    nums.append(random.randint(1,20))
```

I would then like to search 'nums' for a specific number, say '12' and use an if statement to print if it showed up and where in the list. Something like this:

```
if len(newNums) == 0:
    print('No, 12 is not a part of this integer list')
elif len(newNums) < 2:
    print('Yes, 12 is in the list at index', newNums[0])
else:
    print('Yes, 12 is in the list at indices', newNums)
```

In this case, 'newNums' is the list where I have the locations listed of where '12' is inside of the 'nums' list.

I tried a few different things with a for loop that didn't get me anywhere and then I found something on here that looked like this:

```
newNums = (i for i,x in enumerate(nums) if x == 12)
```

However, when I try to print that it does not do what I am looking for. I must have misunderstood its purpose. My understanding of the `enumerate` function is that it provides the index of where the value is located, followed by the value; ex: `[0,1]`, `[1,8]`, `[2,6]` etc. I am reading that code to mean: give me the i value in a pair of `[i,x]` inside the list (`nums`) if the `x == 12`.

I am new to python within the past couple of weeks, so any advice is welcome. I may just be misunderstanding how the code works.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem here is that `newNums`:

```
newNums = (i for i,x in enumerate(nums) if x == 12) # a generator
```

is a **generator**, and as far as I know, you cannot call `len(..)` on a genrator and the printing does not show it elements, but only that it is an enumerator.

You can use **list comprehension** to construct a list. All you have to do is replace the round brackets (`(..)`) with square ones (`[..]`):

```
newNums = [i for i,x in enumerate(nums) if x == 12] # a list
#         ^                                       ^
```

Finally a small note:

> My understanding of the `enumerate` function is that it provides the index of where the value is located, followed by the value; ex: `[0,1]`, `[1,8]`, `[2,6]` etc.

You are correct, except that your syntax seems to suggest that it emits *lists*, it emits *tuples*, so `(0,1)`, `(1,8)`,... but this is in this context a minor detail.

Answer (score 3):

the small problem with your code is that

```
newNums = (i for i,x in enumerate(nums) if x == 12)
```

is a [generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) (e.g. `len` will not work on it). what you want is a [list (comprehension)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
newNums = [i for i,x in enumerate(nums) if x == 12]
```

with this the rest of your code works as you expect it.